# How to pass a variable on p:commandButton ajax request

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem in handling a query string variable. I have a variable edit, that I append in the query string. By default it's true, meaning my page would be in edit mode, if false then the page would be in view mode. So in the page I read and assign the value of the edit query string variable to my backing bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class UserAction { 
    private boolean edit;
    //setter, getter
}

<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="edit" value="#{userAction.edit}" />
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```

Which works fine on first load of the page. For example edit=true, my page renders all the input components, but when I hit the clear button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Reset" process="@this" update="@form" action="#{userAction.clear()}">
    <f:actionListener
        type="org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener" />
    <f:param name="edit" value="true"></f:param>
</p:commandButton>
```

The form re-renders without the input components because edit parameter is now false.

I tried, replacing RequestScoped with ViewScoped, but it seems that f:viewParam is not working for some reason.

I also tried setPropertyActionListener, the edit setter is called but when the getter is called the value reverts back to false.

I know that it is a scope problem because I don't encounter the same error with almost the same code but with ConversationScoped. But I just need this backing bean to be RequestScope.

Any idea?

Comment: The answer would be to nest a `<f:param name="edit" value="true">`, but you already have that. Which PF version are you using? Do you see the `edit=true` parameter in the HTTP traffic monitor when the button is pressed?

Comment: I'm using PF version 3.5. Unfortunately that's my problem I don't see edit=true in the parameter, so edit is reset to false I guess. I'm using fiddler to analyze http request.

Comment: Works for me. What's the generated HTML output of the command button? HTTP traffic can by the way also easily be analyzed with browser's builtin developer toolset.

Comment: Here's the generated html: <button type="submit" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'userForm:formId:j_idt127:resetButton:j_idt133',process:'userForm:formId:j_idt127:resetButton:j_idt133',update:'userForm:formId'});return false;" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" name="userForm:formId:j_idt127:resetButton:j_idt133" id="userForm:formId:j_idt127:resetButton:j_idt133" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Reset</span></button>. I've also tried using FireBug but same result. Are you refering to Http request or post parameter?